# Backquote usage when selecting a full path in BigQuery

Tags: select, syntax, google-bigquery

Is there any potential difference in usage in standard Bigquery SQL between

```
SELECT * from `project.dataset.table`
```

and

```
SELECT * from `project`.`dataset`.`table`
```

From the limited tests I did on public datasets, it seems there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

The

```
`
```

character stands for literal meaning, that is, you might need to create a database/table/column which has a name which is also a keyword in the language. The character above ensures that the resource is interpreted as a resource name, even if it's otherwise could be mistaken with a keyword or would otherwise be syntactically incorrect. Try to create a table called `select` just for fun and see the difference between encapsulating it and not encapsulating it.

Comment: you cannot define table name as 'Foo.Bar'. It will throw error.

Comment: @Ash_max In MySQL `create table \`Foo.Bar\`(lorem int);` works. Have you tried the same in Google BigQuery? I do not have it installed, but I strongly suspect that this should work there as well.

Comment: @LajosArpad Yeah, this statement fails with a BigQuery specific exception basically saying dots are not allowed in identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery considers column, table and other database object names as Identifiers. These identifiers can be quoted or unquoted and follow a specific structure. Quoted identifiers are enclosed by backtick (`) and are generally used while dealing with reserved keywords. Refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#identifiers).

Backticks are usually used to select columns and tables from the source database, but these are not compulsory since they don’t make any difference and return the same result without using it.

For example the following queries will work and return the same result in BigQuery.

```
select * from project.dataset.table         #(unquoted)
select * from `project.dataset.table`       #(quoted)
select * from `project`.`dataset`.`table`   #(quoted)
```